# Outro vs Rest of Song - Clashing Meaning? The Hills (The Weeknd)

Tags: meaning

At the end of the (studio) recording, a woman says the following:

> Ewedihalehu/ Yene konjo, ewedihalehu/ Yene fikir, fikir, fikir, fikir/
>   Yene fikir, fikir, fikir, fikir

This means:

> I love you very much/ My beautiful, I love you very much/ My love, love, love, love/ My love, love, love, love

in Amharic (a language native to Ethiopia (he is of Ethiopian decent)).

This doesn't seem to fit with the song, which means this:

> The song’s narrative is about a sinking sexual affair in which Abel sets the record straight about what this woman means to him, and reminding her that she is an equally guilty party in this affair.

How does this relate to the song?

Music video here:

https://youtu.be/yzTuBuRdAyA

It starts at around 3:35, it's kind of hard to hear.

[Source (Explicit)](http://genius.com/The-weeknd-the-hills-lyrics/)

Comment: Hi guys his song is actually demonic go listen to it backwards on YouTube.....it says that "im the devil look at it im the devil."then in his chorus he sings of meeting his lucifer

Answer (score 5):

I just read that those words are translated from Ethopia and they are masculine in form, which means its the way a woman would say I Love You to a man.  The man would use a different word for love that is feminine in nature.  So at the end its the girl telling him lies...because there is no actual love there.

Answer (score 3):

I am Ethiopian myself, and in the song that part is spoken/sang is a female voice. The words chosen from Tesfaye also suggest that a woman because the its gender. Therefore this part is refering to a girlfriend loving him. This symbolises th e lies between the affair and that it may be purely sexual and doesn't include emotion

Answer (score 1):

The song's subject matter is not necessarily a love but his relationship with addiction. His addiction is personified in the video. The lyrics make sense

Comment: Is this a complete answer? The last sentence cuts off.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, to me it seems like it's the female party saying to him (most likely she's caught feelings after their quiet affair), "I love you I love you I love you" and he's saying, "whoa, this isn't about love, this is just sex...you have a boyfriend, this is just what it is, a good time on the low, not a relationship"

Comment: Please don't use profanity, it is automatically reported and we have to clean it up.

Comment: Profanity is not automatically reported.  However, we discourage its use since many of our readers are young.

Answer (score 0):

I am Ethiopian and "ewedihalew" are the form of "I love you" you would say to a man.

For a woman you would say "ewedeshalew" not "ewedihalew", so that girl is trying to say "I love you, Abel" which doesn't fit with the song. I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no woman. The affair is with drugs. There is no love. There is only addiction. She (the white girl) speaks his language to tell him she loves him but she has other addicts just like he has other addictions.

Comment: Hi. Could you give us more details on what you are saying? Do you have some sources?